# Can't Insert Background Image

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to update my site and have been having extreme difficulty with implementing an image into the site background.

I tried to create two divs, one for each side (as I want the output to be image1 - lets call it leftbg.png then content in the middle, followed by image2 - lets call it rightbg.png on the right).

So I have put the divs in the body as so:

```
<body>
    <div id="leftbg">
        <div id="rightbg">
             content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And in the css file I have:

```
#leftbg {
float: left;
width: 22.5% (body is 55%);
background: url(images/leftbg.png) no-repeat;
z-index: 999
}
```

However this is not producing anything. I think it might be because my body code includes a background already, and I have tried to put z-indexes, such that my leftbg class would be dominant over the body class, however I am aware z-indexes have many problems.

This is the body css code:

```
body {
font:11px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
color:#666;
background:maroon url(image/backgrd.png);
z-index: 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would the `body` be 55%? `#leftbg`s 22.5% width means it's 22.5% of the width of it's parent, in this case the `body`. I don't see `body{width:55%}`.

Comment: Ah I was trying to mean 22.5% of the entire thing. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a `height` to `#leftbg`. Example:

```
#leftbg {
float: left;
height: 80px;
width: 22.5%;
background: url(images/leftbg.png) no-repeat;
z-index: 999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest restructuring your HTML like this:

```
<div class="bgs">
    <div class="bg left"></div>
    <div class="bg right"></div>
</div>

<div class="fake-body">
    <h1>Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like this with your CSS:

```
.bgs{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.bg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.bg.left{
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.bg.right{
    right: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

.fake-body{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I think that's pretty clean. Feel free to replace the red and blue background colors with your desired background images.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y2w1vo3/)

Comment: Ya this worked decently! It got the images on the positions I wanted which was sweet, but it didn't align the way I wanted. Am playing with it now.

Comment: Cool, post another jsfiddle if you can't figure it out and I'll take a look.

Comment: I can't get it to align properly, should I use another position form, such as "position: initial or position: relative"?